# zii.widgets.CListView (SummaryText) Yii

Tags: php, yii, clistview

How to get rid or reposition the Summary Text completely? I don't want that to be seen at all.

Instead it should be on the top or somewhere else, because it takes a entire space as seen in the picture below:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', 
                array(
                      'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
                      'ajaxUpdate' => true,
                      'enablePagination'=>true,
                      'summaryText'=>

                      'itemView'=>'_list',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
                      'sortableAttributes'=>array(
                                                  'Price',
                                                  'Year',
                                                  'Lenght'
                                                  ),

                      )

                    );
```

I would like to have something like picture in right side. Left side is the current situation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the template option for ClistView. Here is a discussion on the feature http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24952-what-is-template-in-clistview/ With some examples.

You can also find details about the options in the official documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#template-detail

Comment: But it still takes up some space on the right side , the template made the text disappear but i need the sortable attributes on the top of the List view , not sure how to do it..

Comment: It is a matter of creating styles and a proper layout, but who knows what there you are using... you can build your own layout for it as you are the one that knows what you use.